# some confusion regarding empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $X=  \{ a, b, c\}$

Then choose the  correct option

$1.$ $\varnothing \in  X $

$2.$ $\{\varnothing\} \in  X $

$3.$$\varnothing \subseteq  X $

$4.$ $\{\varnothing\} \subseteq  X $

My attempt :  I think all option $1$, $2$, $3$,and $4 $are  true because  empty set  contains no elements.

Comment: But is the empty set an *element* of $X$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson empty set is  empty  i mean  it is  subset of all set

Comment: @jasmine: The members of $X$ are $a,b$, and $c$; is $\varnothing$ in that list? If not, it cannot be a member of $X$.

Comment: oks thanks u  sir @BrianM.Scott  that mean option 1, 3 are true

Comment: But, jasmine, the first option says the empty set is *an element* of $X$. So the question is, is the empty set *an element* of $X$?

Comment: oks  let me think more @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty set is still an object. It **contains** nothing, but it **is** something.

It sometimes help to think of sets as plastic bags. We can put all sorts of objects into plastic bags. We can even put plastic bags into plastic bags. The empty set is an empty plastic bag. On the other hand, $X$ is a plastic bag containing letters $a$, $b$, $c$.

Option 1 asks us, if there is an empty plastic bag in $X$? No there isn't: there's three items in there, $a$, $b$, $c$, but no empty plastic bag. So, this is false.

Option 2 presents us with $\{ \emptyset\}$ a plastic bag containing one thing: another empty plastic bag. Can we find such an object in $X$? Again, we can't: there are three items in there, none of which are plastic bags.

Option 3 presents us with out empty plastic bag again, but asks us about subsets. The question now is, can we find everything in our empty plastic bag inside $X$? Well, there's nothing in our empty plastic bag and all of that "nothing" lies inside $X$. For every one of the $0$ objects we could pull out of the empty plastic bag, they all belong to $X$. This makes this option true!

Option 4 asks us if our plastic bag $\{\emptyset\}$, containing just an empty plastic bag, also has this property: that no matter what object we pull from it, this object will belong in $X$. In this case, we can pull only the empty plastic bag from $\{ \emptyset\}$. Can we find this empty plastic bag in $X$? No; indeed this option is logically equivalent to option 1.

I don't know if this analogy will help you, but it sometimes helps my students.